# Expo code in react native is always giving error

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-navigation-drawer

I am trying to run some expo sample code in Snack for drawer navigation that is taken straight from the docs at [Drawer Navigation in React Native](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation#minimal-example-of-drawer-based-navigation)

Snack code is at [Code Sample for this issue](https://snack.expo.io/@sun21170/16c137?platform=android&name=Hello%20React%20Navigation%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.7%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.8.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.9.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.7.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.9.0%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.0.1%2Creact-native-reanimated%40%5E1.7.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40%5E3.0.2%2Creact-native-screens%40%5E2.9.0%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E2.15.1&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fdrawer-based-navigation.js)

However, its always failing to run as it should i.e. I get a blue screen as below.

**Question:**
What could be the reason causing this? I tried in expo 38 and 39, but still the issue remains. I have tried it on both android and ios simulators that are available in Snack.

[image: Blue Screen in Snack Expo React Native app]

App.js code is as below.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go back home" />
    </View>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`
like mentioned [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) , it will pull the right versions for your expo version.

Comment: ,but that will not solve the problem in Snack, which is an online editor for react native code. What you are suggesting is for a project created on a laptop.